Defining methods of several classes in one function using templates
Suppose we have two classes
class A {
   A Method();
}

class B {
   B Method();
}

Method function does some repetitive work, for the example, let's suppose it just returns class's copy.
How can I define this 2 function in 1 using templates? Is it possible?
I've tried to do something like
template <class C>
C C::Method() {
    return *this;
}

Clang gives me error: Nested name specifier 'N::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization

" it just returns class...." You can't return a "class" but only an object of a class-type. Terminology/terms are very important in c++. Sometimes it may affect the interpretation of your question.

Class A and B are unrelated types, so they cannot have a common method. XY Problem?

Use a class template instead of creating two unrelated types?

@user12002570 regarding XY problem, are there some ways to solve this problem except class inheritance and MethodImpl function in base class? bc even int this approach we stll have repetitive MethodImpl() call in 2 classes.

Whatever you do here, you'll always end up with two distinct member functions because there are two distinct classes. It may however be possible to remove repetition while writing the code(maybe using macro etc).

You can use macro like this demo and in this answer although I would advise against using macros at all.

You can't define multiple unrelated functions with syntax like that, but you can add a member to a class by inheriting from a template class.
template <class T>
class Cloneable
{
    T Method() { return *static_cast<T*>(this); }
}

class A : public Cloneable<A> {}

class B : public Cloneable<B> {}

If you have C++23, you can even drop the cast with an explicit object parameter
class Cloneable
{
    template <class T>
    T Method(this T self) { return self; }
}

class A : public Cloneable {}

class B : public Cloneable {}


@JeJo Why "almost" ? It is CRTP unless I overlooked something

@JeJo the static_cast will protect against mistakes, but not much can protect against malice

Usually you don't need a method to make a copy since the copy constructor and copy-assignment operator exist for that purpose.
But if you really want to do it anyway, you can solve your issue using CRTP:
template <typename Actual>
struct Impl
{
    Actual copy()
    {
        return *static_cast<Actual*>(this);
    }
};

struct A : public Impl<A>
{};

struct B : public Impl<B>
{};

This way, no repetition is performed and both will have their own copy() function with their actual type.


are there some ways to solve this problem except class inheritance and MethodImpl function in base class?

Although not recommended, you can use macro remove repetition as shown below:
#define CreateMethod(Type) Type Type::Method() { return *this;}
class A {
   A Method();
};

class B {
   B Method();
};

CreateMethod(A) 
CreateMethod(B) 

